# ios7, spritekit: drawing non sprite objects onto the canvas of a sprite

Tags: ios7, drawing, xcode5, sprite

I am working on a game where I need to create an enormous "world" over which a rocket ship flies. On this world, I have to programmatically generate various simple background elements. There needs to be a record of the path, so I can't use parallax effects to give the feeling of motion.

When I create the background elements using SKShapeNode and SKLabelNode objects, I get terrible performance, because I literally have to add thousands of these nodes.

Is there a way to draw text and lines directly onto a sprite object?